# arithmetic expression tree using c language

Tags: c, binary-tree, expression-trees

I need to figure out how to create an arithmetic expression tree.

I can create simple binary tree using just set of numbers. There is a code example below:

This is simple node that for my tree.

```
typedef struct _node {
    int key;
    struct _node *left, *right;
} node;
```

This is how I add new node to my binary tree:

```
node* add_tree(node *root, int val) {    
    if(NULL == root) {
        root = crnode(val);
    }    
    if (val < root->key) {
        if (NULL == root->left) {
            root->left = crnode(val);
        }
        else {
            add_tree(root->left, val);
        }
    }

    if (val > root->key) {
        if (NULL == root->right) {
            root->right = crnode(val);
        }
        else {
            add_tree(root->right, val);
        }
    }    
    return root;
}
```

This is main function and steps how I add new number to tree:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {    
        node *tree = add_tree(NULL, 5);
        tree = add_tree(tree, 6);
        tree = add_tree(tree, 7);
        tree = add_tree(tree, 3);
        return 0;
    }
```

My question is: how to transform this code that I can using not just a number but and operator (e.g + - / *).

For example I need to transform an expression 5 * (10 - 5) + 6 * 4 to tree. How can I make it?

Comment: As this sounds very much like homework, I'm not going to offer any code, but I will offer a minor help in design. In keeping with the tree concept, what would you see in an expression like that you posted that would be a good fit for the "root" node versus the "leaves?" Put another way, how might you generalize that expression into a repeatable form? Then, extend that to how you might traverse the tree to obtain the original expression..

Comment: In C, `'*'` is an integer.  You can store it in the key but you will need a structure member to distinguish between operators and values.

Comment: thanks for comments guys. it's very important for me. yes I know that sounds as homework, but it is not a homework. my main problem with understanding process - "How I can add some node that not a number". For example if I create binary tree is a simple for me, because I just compare my number and add they to the right or left node (depending with a value). But expression is some dificult for me, because I don't know how it should works when I add something to the node.

Comment: You have to have two types of nodes: an operator and an operand. Operator has two children: left and right. Operand has no children.

Comment: so if we can see on the main I add to tree some number and the tree makes with a rules. But wchich rules I need to implement that make expression tree. So one thing that I know that number are leaf and the operators are internal nodes. but right now it does not help me :) and I feel very stupid, cause I work as a programme more than 2 years. but mathematic is very hard for me. and I need help.

Comment: ok, about two types of nodes - this is greate idea. I will do it. So i will add one check to the method add that will check input symbol. For example if it (* + / -) I will create nodeOperator in other cases I will create nodeOperand. am I right?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander That's right. Except, if you want to have numbers > 9, you'll have to do a bit more work since such numbers don't fit into a single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A node in your expression is one of two things: an operator or a value.  So you need to delineate.  There are several ways to do this, but since this is homework I'm inclined to be a little cagey and let you work something out using the programming concepts you have learned thus far.

So I decided to help you by showing what your tree might look like if you had your nodes working:

```
      +
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  *       *
 / \     / \
5   -   6   4
   / \
  10  5
```

You might want to drop the notion of 'building a tree', and instead think of it as 'constructing an expression'.  It could be what's holding you back.  You might end up with some functions that are used like this:

```
node *expr = subtract(value(10), value(5));
```

That builds a part of the tree.  See what's going on? =)

Comment: thanks a lot. yes I don't need ready made solution. I will make this progaram on objective c for an app. But I have chosen "C language" because it very simple for understanding for many people.
So, yes now I see what is going on. But I have a problem with understanding why the "+" operator is root of tree. Yes I see the tree is correct and I can make this structure by myself (I mean in graphic variant). But I dont know how to make this in code. So firs one as I understand we need to get separete expresion e.g. 6*4. am I right?

Comment: Hint: the return type of the `value` function is also a `node*`.  As for your question, the `+` node is at the top because that's where it ended up when considering the 'left' and 'right' of an equation using operator precedence.  Do you have to actually parse the expression from a string and build the tree, or do you simply hard-code it?  Parsing is trickier, but in either case your tree should come out the same.

Comment: oh, excuse me. I don't add this info. Yes the expression based on a string, "5*(10-5)+6*4". I think I understand now how it looks in hard code variant. it also very important for me thanks.

Comment: Okay, so you're halfway there.  I think you can handle the rest.  When you're parsing, you can basically build your expression on the fly by only looking at one token at a time, maintaining a pointer to the current node, and doing some recursion (if you encounter an operator with a stronger precedence than the caller's operator).  Have fun! =)

Comment: in any case, thank you. I think I don't have basic knowledge in this topic, because it hard for me. Tree is a very abstract thing :)